# Visual Studio And Ms Access VB.net Dataset Fill By is not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I have a table called GRN with MS Access Database
as shown below

```
grn_id (Autonumber)
grn_number (Text)
grn_date (Date/Time)
invoice_number (Text)
invoice_date (Date/Time)
voucher_number (Text)
supplier (Text)
```

I have created a data set with VB.Net Visual Studio 2012
in the data Set I have created a table adapter and a query
with the following code

```
SELECT        grn_id, grn_number, grn_date, invoice_number, invoice_date, voucher_number, supplier
FROM            grn
WHERE        (grn_number = ?)
```

And named it as FillByGRN

In the form I have added the following code

```
Me.GrnTableAdapter.FillByGRN(dataTable:=Me.DocmanDataSet.grn, grn_number:=finfo.Text)
```

When I Run The application and Give the textfield finfo a value and click on my button to fill is is not working and stopped on the line of filling the table adapter.

Any Solution Please

Comment: Two things to check: 1. Does your query return results if run directly against the DB? 2. Place the FillBy line in Try/Catch and see if there's any exception?

Comment: One more thing: make sure your runtime connection string is pointing to the same database that you *think* it is. Often times the design-time connection string is different than the runtime one and we keep banging our head against the wall.

Comment: I have executed the query directly in the query builder and worked perfectly when I used the Try catch I got get exception of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered

Comment: Use `Me.GrnTableAdapter.FillByGRN(Me.<DataSetName.DataTableName>, fileInfo.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the exception you mentioned, you don't seem to have Jet Database Engine driver installed on your machine. Either download and install that driver, or in case you're running against Access 2010 or later, use `ACE.OLEDB` connection string instead of the old-school `Jet.OLEDB`.

The connection string looks like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<Access Database Path>;
```

Persist Security Info=False;

You can read more about OLEDB connection strings [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/).